# 128X128 icon loads as a 16X16 in one project and as a 32X32 icon in another

Tags: .net, vb.net

I worked on a project some time ago for which I bought and downloaded a bunch of .ICO files to use as button icons.  The bulk of the .ICO files include within their properties a 128X128 size designation.

When attached to buttons in my old project, those .ICO images display as 32X32 images.  Now I am trying to rework the program from scratch.  When I try to reload the .ICO files into my new program buttons I get 16X16 images instead.

I'd like to figure out how to tell the VB designer which to use.  I know that there must be a way to do this as the two projects are behaving differently.  Thanks and cheers!